# CPP compile error: included files not found

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors

In my app.cpp file I have the following line: `#include "indri/Repository.hpp"`

However when I run make (makefile below): I get the following error:

```
indri/Repository.hpp:22:32: error: indri/Parameters.hpp: No such file or directory
```

The reason is that the Repository.hpp includes other hpp in the same folder but it uses "`indri/*.hpp`" instead of just "`*.hpp`".

What am I missing ?
thanks

```
## your application name here
APP=myapp
SRC=$(APP).cpp
## extra object files for your app here
OBJ=

prefix = /usr/local
exec_prefix = ${prefix}
libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir = ${prefix}/include
INCPATH=-I$(includedir)
LIBPATH=-L$(libdir)
CXXFLAGS=-DPACKAGE_NAME=\"Indri\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"indri\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"5.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"Indri\ 5.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"project@lemurproject.org\" -DYYTEXT_POINTER=1 -DINDRI_STANDALONE=1 -DHAVE_LIBM=1 -DHAVE_LIBPTHREAD=1 -DHAVE_LIBZ=1 -DHAVE_NAMESPACES= -DISNAN_IN_NAMESPACE_STD= -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_FSEEKO=1 -DHAVE_EXT_ATOMICITY_H=1 -DP_NEEDS_GNU_CXX_NAMESPACE=1 -DHAVE_MKSTEMP=1 -DHAVE_MKSTEMPS=1 -DNDEBUG=1  -g -O3 $(INCPATH)
CPPLDFLAGS  =  -lindri -lz -lpthread -lm 

all:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SRC) -o $(APP) $(OBJ) $(LIBPATH) $(CPPLDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(APP)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget to add the current directory?

```
## your application name here
APP=myapp
SRC=$(APP).cpp
## extra object files for your app here
OBJ=

prefix = /usr/local
exec_prefix = ${prefix}
libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir = ${prefix}/include
INCPATH=-I$(includedir) -I.  # can you spot the difference?
LIBPATH=-L$(libdir)
CXXFLAGS=-DPACKAGE_NAME=\"Indri\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"indri\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"5.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"Indri\ 5.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"project@lemurproject.org\" -DYYTEXT_POINTER=1 -DINDRI_STANDALONE=1 -DHAVE_LIBM=1 -DHAVE_LIBPTHREAD=1 -DHAVE_LIBZ=1 -DHAVE_NAMESPACES= -DISNAN_IN_NAMESPACE_STD= -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_FSEEKO=1 -DHAVE_EXT_ATOMICITY_H=1 -DP_NEEDS_GNU_CXX_NAMESPACE=1 -DHAVE_MKSTEMP=1 -DHAVE_MKSTEMPS=1 -DNDEBUG=1  -g -O3 $(INCPATH)
CPPLDFLAGS  =  -lindri -lz -lpthread -lm 

all:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SRC) -o $(APP) $(OBJ) $(LIBPATH) $(CPPLDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(APP)
```

Comment: well, I've just downloaded the makefile from the Lemur website. Now it works thanks, did they probably forget ? strange..